# Cannot watch Coursera's video lectures

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, laptop, sony-vaio

I cannot watch [Coursera's](http://www.coursera.org/) video lectures. What's wrong and must be fixed?  I only see a black page and then nothing happens, no matter how long I wait. Should I change the setting or are some plugins needed?

[image]

Comment: What about other browsers, do they display the video ?

Comment: You have click to play or something like that enabled? What does error console say? (Hit F12 to bring it up)

Comment: @Sathya: It says "failed to load resource".

Comment: @Lamb: I didn't try FireFox but Internet Explorer 8 doesn't even open that black page. It says "done, but with errors on page".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a connectivity problem. Posted screenshot shows that plug-in loads without a problem, but it cannot get the content to show. Also, you can try right-clicking in coursera video screens and choose "download video". By the way, what's your answer to Lamb's question?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't notice that it is possible to download the videos.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not a connectivity problem; it's a Chrome problem.  Numerous people - including me - have had this issue.  A bug (at least one!) has been reported:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162784

It looks like they're having trouble reproducing the problem; Additional data posted to this bug report may help get it solved!

I was not able to get any of the suggested work-arounds to fix the problem.  Videos play fine in Firefox on my machine.